# Determine whether a magazine contains the words needed for a ransom note

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is a website Question on Hackrrank called Hash Tables: Ransom Note:

Given the words in the magazine and the words in the ransom note, print "Yes" if we can replicate the ransom note exactly using whole words from the magazine; otherwise, print "No".

Here is an example input:

```
6 4
give me one grand today night
give one grand today
```

Output: Yes

And another:

```
6 5
two times three is not four
two times two is four
```

Output: No

---

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):

    #Creating 2 Empty Dictionaries for the "Magazine" and the "Note" then filling them up
    UniqueWordsMag = set(magazine)
    UniqueCountMag = [0]*len(UniqueWordsMag)
    UniqueWordDictMag = dict(zip(UniqueWordsMag, UniqueCountMag))

    UniqueWordsNote= set(note)
    UniqueCountNote = [0]*len(UniqueWordsNote)
    UniqueWordDictNote = dict(zip(UniqueWordsNote, UniqueCountNote))

    for i in magazine:
        if i in list(UniqueWordDictMag.keys()):
            UniqueWordDictMag[i] += 1

    for i in note:
        if i in list(UniqueWordDictNote.keys()):
            UniqueWordDictNote[i] += 1


    #Checking for existance in the magazine then checking for the correct count, print no if it does not fulfil conditions
    Success = False
    DesiredCount = len(note)
    Count = 0

    for index,i in enumerate(UniqueWordsNote):
        if i in list(UniqueWordDictMag.keys()):
            if UniqueWordDictNote[i] <= UniqueWordDictMag[i]:
                Count += UniqueWordDictNote[i]
            else:
                break
        else:
            break

    if Count == DesiredCount:
        Success = True
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

It's called from this `main` program, that's provided by the challenge:

> ```
> def main():
>     mn = input().split()
>
>     m = int(mn[0])
>
>     n = int(mn[1])
>
>     magazine = input().rstrip().split()
>
>     note = input().rstrip().split()
>
>     checkMagazine(magazine, note)
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     main()
> ```

My code is currently taking too long on some lists (e.g. lists of size 30,000 or more).  Are there any optimisations I can make to make this a bit more legible and faster?

Comment: Please link to the problem.

Comment: Check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, especially the suggestion to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.

Answer (score 4):

You're making it enormously complicated. This is a job for [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    print('No' if Counter(note) - Counter(magazine) else 'Yes')
```

Comment: I can't find where [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is documented to evaluate false if any element is negative.  Please could you enlighten me?  It does seem a very useful property.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's not really what happens. As the doc says about the `-` operation: *"the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less"*. So my difference Counter doesn't have negatives. I think a Counter is false for the standard reason: being empty. What I really check is whether there are any *positives*. That is, whether any words needed for the note remain unaccounted for after discounting by the magazine words.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I understand it better now.  I'm not so fluent in Python, so didn't recognise the idiom!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Counter`, but even for not using `Counter` you made it very complicated. Doing it with `dict` and keeping your structure, you could do this:

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    
    mag_ctr = dict.fromkeys(magazine, 0)
    note_ctr = dict.fromkeys(note, 0)
    
    for word in magazine:
        mag_ctr[word] += 1
    
    for word in note:
        note_ctr[word] += 1
    
    for word in note_ctr:
        if note_ctr[word] > mag_ctr.get(word, 0):
            print('No')
            break
    else:
        print('Yes')
```

Just for fun, while I'm here... this trivial solution also got accepted despite being slow:

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    try:
        for word in note:
            magazine.remove(word)
        print('Yes')
    except:
        print('No')
```

I like it because it's simple. We can do a similar but fast one by using a Counter for the magazine (none needed for the note, saving memory compared to two Counters):

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    available = Counter(magazine)
    for word in note:
        if not available[word]:
            print('No')
            break
        available[word] -= 1
    else:
        print('Yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

Counting the number of occurrences of an item already exists in the `list.count(item)` function.
To continue with the approach of jumping out of code as soon as possible with your break out of a for loop, we can use a generator inside an `any` evaluation like so:

```
def check_magazine(magazine, note):
    print("No" if any(note.count(word) > magazine.count(word) for word in set(note)) else "Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

General (non-performance) review:

There are several variables assigned but never used.  For example:

> ```
>     mn = input().split()
>     m = int(mn[0])
>     n = int(mn[1])
> ```

We never use `m` or `n`, so this can just be replaced by

> ```
>     input()
> ```

(I later discovered that `main()` was provided by the challenge, so you're not to blame for this.  OTOH, there's nothing to stop you improving the boilerplate you were given!)

Similarly:

> ```
>     Success = True
>     print("Yes")
> ```

`Success` is never used; just remove it.

As noted elsewhere,

> ```
> #Creating 2 Empty Dictionaries for the "Magazine" and the "Note" then filling them up
> UniqueWordsMag = set(magazine)
> UniqueCountMag = [0]*len(UniqueWordsMag)
> UniqueWordDictMag = dict(zip(UniqueWordsMag, UniqueCountMag))
>
> UniqueWordsNote= set(note)
> UniqueCountNote = [0]*len(UniqueWordsNote)
> UniqueWordDictNote = dict(zip(UniqueWordsNote, UniqueCountNote))
>
> for i in magazine:
>     if i in list(UniqueWordDictMag.keys()):
>         UniqueWordDictMag[i] += 1
>
> for i in note:
>     if i in list(UniqueWordDictNote.keys()):
>         UniqueWordDictNote[i] += 1
> ```

is much simpler using a Counter:

```
import collections
magazine_words = collections.Counter(magazine)
note_words = collections.Counter(note)
```

And the test

> ```
> #Checking for existance in the magazine then checking for the correct count, print no if it does not fulfil conditions
> Success = False
> DesiredCount = len(note)
> Count = 0
>
> for index,i in enumerate(UniqueWordsNote):
>     if i in list(UniqueWordDictMag.keys()):
>         if UniqueWordDictNote[i] <= UniqueWordDictMag[i]:
>             Count += UniqueWordDictNote[i]
>         else:
>             break
>     else:
>         break
>
> if Count == DesiredCount:
> ```

reduces to just

```
if magazine_words & note_words == note_words:
```

Comment: That `m`/`n` part is kinda not their fault, you're reviewing the site's code there, not the OP's.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear in the question (and I don't follow links to read specs, as questions should be self-contained).  And I was going to praise the correct use of a `main` guard, too!  Is everything from `def main:` onwards not OP code then?

Comment: Ha, that praise would've been funny. Yes, only the body of the `checkMagazine` function is the OP's (the `def`-line is provided by the site, too).

Comment: Oops actually I *might* be slightly wrong there. At least at [the URL I found](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem) (you can close the login dialog by clicking the X or pressing escape), the given code is not in a main *function* but just inside a guard. I wish the people would just link to the sources, sigh. Anyway, I think your edit is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for i in magazine:
        if i in list(UniqueWordDictMag.keys()):
            UniqueWordDictMag[i] += 1

    for i in note:
        if i in list(UniqueWordDictNote.keys()):
            UniqueWordDictNote[i] += 1
```

Avoid creating a list and just iterate over the keys

```
for i in magazine:
        if i in UniqueWordDictMag.keys():
            UniqueWordDictMag[i] += 1

    for i in note:
        if i in UniqueWordDictNote.keys():
            UniqueWordDictNote[i] += 1
```

Comment: No need for `.keys()`, either.

Comment: Actually the entire condition is unneeded. You *know* that `i` is in there.